# Can’t read the data of ‘file.jpg’. Is it in a supported JavaScript type (String, Blob, ArrayBuffer, etc)?

Tags: javascript, string, types, blob

this  is my code

its work fine on local server but does not work on my unix server

im struck on this error 7 days..

```
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "DOCUMENT DETAILS.zip");
});
```

Comment: please show some more details e.g. what does `saveAs(...) `

Answer (score 0):

```
function base64toBlob(base64Data,contentType) {

            var sliceSize = 1024;
            contentType = contentType || '';
            var byteCharacters = window.atob(base64Data);
            var bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
            var slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
            var byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);

            for (var sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex < slicesCount; ++sliceIndex) {
                var begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
                var end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);

                var bytes = new Array(end - begin);
                for (var offset = begin, i = 0; offset < end; ++i, ++offset) {
                    bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);

                }

                byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);




            }

            return new Blob(byteArrays, {
                type : contentType
            });
    }
```